# \ifpdf returns true when using LuaLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, luatex, conditionals

The `ifpdf` package is supposed to detect if pdfTeX is running:

> This package looks for pdfTeX in pdf mode and implements and sets the switch `\ifpdf`.

(from the [`ifpdf` documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/ifpdf))

However, when I compile the following MWE with LuaLaTeX, my document reads

> This is pdfTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifpdf}

\begin{document}
\ifpdf
    This is pdfTeX.
\else
    This is not pdfTeX.
\fi
\end{document}
```

Is this expected and intended behavior? How do I set up a conditional that *only* detects pdfTeX? (The MWE works as expected for XeTeX.)

Comment: Looks OK to me: LuaLaTeX makes PDF files, not DVI.

Comment: @JosephWright Reading the name of the switch literally, yes. But then again, XeTeX produces pdf as well, and the switch returns false for that. Also, the abstract talks about pdfTeX, not pdf output.

Comment: XeTeX _always_ works _via_ the `.xdv` (extended DVI) format, and the PDF is actually made by `xdvipdfmx` which is normally as part of the XeTeX run. `\ifpdf` is about the driver, and in the pdfTeX and LuaTeX cases the 'driver' is direct PDF output.

Comment: use the package `ifluatex` instead with `\ifluatex ... \else ... \fi`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

LuaTeX comes from pdfTeX, it also knows the same modes for PDF and DVI and provides nearly all PDF features of pdfTeX. It knows even `\pdftexversion` and `\pdftexrevision`.
Thus `\ifpdf` has the same semantics here.

The test `\ifpdf` is *not* for testing for an engine. Even if `\ifpdf` is false, then you can have pdfTeX, but pdfTeX in DVI mode. Usually TeX Live and MiKTeX are also using pdfTeX 
for the command `latex`, but generating DVI with pdfTeX in DVI mode.

If you want to know, if pdfTeX and not LuaTeX is running, then you can exclude luatex by
`\ifluatex` of package `ifluatex` and then testing for `\pdftexversion`, for example:

```
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifluatex
  \typeout{This is LuaTeX}%
\else
  \begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\ifx\csname pdftexversion\endcsname\relax
    \typeout{This is neither LuaTeX nor pdfTeX}%
  \else
    \typeout{This is pdfTeX in \ifpdf PDF \else DVI \fi mode}%
  \fi
\fi
```

### Testing for package driver options and …

Some TeX engines and modes can be detected at TeX macro level and the packages (or its configuration files) are automatically loading the right drivers, e.g.:

- pdfTeX and LuaTeX in PDF mode
- XeTeX

DVI drivers are different. The DVI driver program is running *after* the TeX run, thus there is no way of knowing the future. The default is often `dvips`.

Therefore in many cases you won't need complicate switch structures to differentiate between the different TeX compilers, just loading the package is enough:

```
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

In case of package `fontspec` you need to test for the Unicode aware TeX compilers,
for example:

```
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifluatex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  % other LuaTeX setup
\else
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    % other XeTeX setup
  \else
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    % other font setup
  \fi
\fi
```

Comment: using package `ifxetex` is also possible

Comment: Great, thanks! Eventually, I'm looking for a way to have one template that I can use with pdfTeX, luaTeX, or XeTeX, and that loads the packages necessary for each one automatically. My approach after this question is `\ifxetex XeTeX \else\ifluatex LuaTeX \else\ifpdf pdfTeX \else something else \fi\fi\fi`. Not sure if I should've asked that directly in a question?

Comment: I have added some more cases in the answer, but feel free to ask a new question.

Answer (score 5):

use the package `ifluatex` instead with `\ifluatex ... \else ... \fi`