# DeclareUnicodeCharacter: Undefined control sequence

Tags: undefined

The following code used to compile, but I noticed now that it doesn't anymore.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E4}{\"a}
\begin{document}
lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \DeclareUnicodeCharacter 

l.3 \DeclareUnicodeCharacter
                          {00E4}{\"a}
?
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Are you using XeTeX or LuaTeX? In those engines `inputenc` (thus `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`) is ignored.

Comment: Do you need to do that declaration to begin with? I see no reason to.